# VBA: procedure duration lagging with each input file

Tags: vba, excel

My first question. It's kind of an emergency.

I wrote a VBA procedure that takes input Excel files, opens them, goes to the specified sheet and starts copying rows of data, pasting it into an output file that is generated and saved after the procedure is done. The input Excel file is closed after copying the last row. I wrote the procedure so that it does this with all input files in the current folder. After the first input file is closed, another is opened and the procedure repeats itself until all files in the folder are scanned and the correct rows stored in the output file.

Here's the problem. If I run this procedure with only one input file, the duration is roughly 5 seconds. If I do this procedure with two input file, the duration increases to roughly 50 seconds. Three input files give me roughly 450 seconds of work.

I need this procedure to copy rows into the output file from roughly fifty files. If this duration increase continues with the same rate, the final duration will be longer than my expected life span.

Is this normal behaviour for a VBA procedure or am I having RAM issues?

All answers will be appreciated.
Martin

Edit: Here is the gist of the code. I removed the repetitions and variable declarations.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Procedure()

'[all declarations and definitions of fixed arrays]

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

folder_name = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
output_name = folder_name & "\Master_output"

Set Output_File = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
Set Output_File = ActiveWorkbook
Set Output_Sheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

input_fileName = Dir(folder_name & "TVP ENGINE 5.1" & "*.xlsm")

While input_fileName <> ""

'Weeding out the wrong files
If input_fileName Like "TVP ENGINE 5.1*" Then

    k_char_1 = InStr(1, input_fileName, "_", 1)
    k_char_2 = InStr(k_char_1 + 1, input_fileName, "_", 1)
    output_string_1 = Mid(input_fileName, k_char_1 + 1, 4)
    output_string_2 = Mid(input_fileName, k_char_2, Len(input_fileName) - k_char_2 - 4)

    j_lob = 0

    Set Input_File = Workbooks.Open(folder_name & input_fileName)
    Set Input_Sheet = Input_File.Worksheets("EMBEDDED_VALUE")
    Input_Sheet.Activate

    While j_lob < UBound(LOB) + 1

        With Input_Sheet.Range("B:B")
            Set seeker = .Find(LOB(j_lob), LookIn:=xlValues) 'Looks for titles of spreadsheets on a single Excel sheet
            i_input = seeker.Row
        End With

    'Instead of going through the entire Excel sheet, it finds specific spreadsheets on a single Excel sheet and looks
    'for specific labels in those spreadsheets to copy; labels are stored in array >lob_term<
        Select Case seeker 

        Case "TERM"

            j_input = 0

            Do

                output_string = output_string_1 & "_" & LOB(j_lob) & "_" & lob_term(j_input) & output_string_2
                Output_Sheet.Range("A" & i_output).Value = output_string 'Name for each row

            '*** Main Operation: copying ranges from one workbook to another***
                Input_Sheet.Range("D" & i_input + 2 & ":AT" & i_input + 2).Copy
                Output_Sheet.Range("B" & i_output & ":AQ" & i_output).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

                j_input = j_input + 1 'index for the lob_term array
                i_input = i_input + 1 'index for location on Input_Sheet
                i_output = i_output + 1 'index for location on Output_Sheet

            Loop Until j_input >= UBound(lob_term) + 1 'lob_term is a fixed value/fixed length array

            j_lob = j_lob + 1 'index for array of names of spreadsheets

    Case others

    '...[identical procedure for different cases]...

    End Select

    Wend

    'Close the current input file, define another
    Workbooks(input_fileName).Close SaveChanges:=False
    input_fileName = Dir()

Else

    input_fileName = Dir()

End If

Wend

   '[setting color theme, freezing panes, etc.]

Output_Fajl.Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Output_File.SaveAs input_fileName:=output_name, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Output_File.Close

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Please post at least the VBA snippet that opens and copies / pastes the range contents so we can answer the question if it is VBA or your coding practice at fault.

Comment: Also, if you have *very* large files, it will drastically affect performance.

Comment: No, it's not normal - you're doing something wrong, but nobody here can tell you what without seeing the code... and even then, if your code is working as intended, but is just inefficient/slow, then you would get much more thorough input on [codereview.se]. Please make sure you read [**how to ask**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**what's on-topic (and what isn't)**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on Code Review, because their rules are wildly different than those of Stack Overflow.

Comment: I added my code.

Comment: You mentioned copying *data* -- which suggests values. Unless you are copying things like formulas and formats, using `Copy` and `Paste` is less efficient than transferring values by directly assigning to a range's `Value` property. That doesn't explain what you are seeing. Nothing in the code that you show explains what you are seeing, although it does contain nested loops and you are describing quadratic behavior. Does the number of times you pass through the inner loop increase with the number of files? It wouldn't hurt to create a counter variable and `Debug.Print` it after the inner loop.

Comment: I thought about loops might be doing something strange. Counter is a good idea. I will try that. Thank you.

I'm using Copy/Paste with Ranges because I'm copying Values as well as formatting. The previous version of the code took Values from the input file and wrote it in the output file. But I wanted to copy the entire row, hoping this would reduce the duration. After that failed, I posted up here.

Will ask my supervisor if formatting is really desperately needed or I can just copy Values.

Comment: Sorry about not posting before, got carried away on other projects.

Long story short, I tried running the macro on a different computer and it worked perfectly. Have no idea why this particular macro refused to work properly when so many much more complex macros worked fine.

Anyway, thanks for sticking with me on this. Your support was very appreciated.

Thanks.